# Is lighting a green screen necessary?

Tags: greenscreen, chromakey

I need a green screen for a project I'm making. However, after some research, they said I need to light it.

I didn't think I'd have to light it, and it looks to complicated. As long as there are no shadows, would it be ok to not go through complicated steps to evenly light it and just use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd probably want to light it anyway, as it will make it easier to pull a key if it's properly lit. The farther you can keep it away from the objects or talent you'll be keying, the better. But light is essential to accurately capturing color, so if you can light it, you should. You want it to be evenly lit so that you don't have to choose too wide of a color range to key out.

Comment: I must agree. Have done it with and without proper lighting. Had to spend over an hour in premiere and AE trying to get the full key.

Comment: I don't understand why lighting is so important...  if you are keying out a particular hue, why does it matter how bright it is? And yet, it's like it's not keying on hue at all because darker instances of the same hue are NOT being keyed out, when totally different colors are already being removed!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer you received. Without lighting you will have a tough
time keying the effect you want. You can use table lamps to light the screen up if need be. But, like was stated, you just have to watch out for the shadows.

Answer (score 0):

You also want to avoid shadows from being lit only from the front. Try to go from above and on the sides going across so they are independent of the subjects lighting. Otherwise you will get a messing key and have blotches of grey or clipping in the subject.